# Link two asynchronous actions for both to succeed or fail together (move file + database save)

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, callback, filesystems

I have two asynchronous actions with callback. I would like to be sure that both of them succeed or fail, but not that one succeed and one fail. It should probably be like one process for both actions which could be revert back ?

Let's illustrate :

```
// In this simplified code, i assume i uploaded a file in a temporary folder.
// Every validations passed and now the goal is to move the file from temporary folder to final destination folder and to save it into database.
// This 'move' and this 'save' are my two async actions with a callback when each action is completed.
// Maybe i am not using the right way / pattern to do it, thank you for enlightening me if necessary.

myController.create = function (req, res, next) {

    // I move the file from oldPath (temp directory) to newPath (final destination)
    mv(oldPath, newPath, function (err) {

        // If err, file is not moved i stop here, went fine. The temp directory is cleared later by the system every X period of time.
        if (err) { return next(err); }

        var file = new FileModel({
          // some properties (name, path...)    
        });

        // The file is now moved, need to save it into database
        file.save(function (err) {

            if (!err) { return next(); } // everything went fine

            // If err, nothing stored in database but the file is still in final folder :o
            // I could unlink the file but it still can fail and keep my file inside destination folder with no database entry.
            fs.unlink(new_path, function (other_err) {
                if (other_err) { return next(other_err); } 
                return next(err);
            }

        });

    });

};
```

In the code above, if first action succeed, nothing guarantee that my second action will succeed too and that i could revert back (my first action) if it fail. The two actions are separate and independant instead of being linked / paired and working together.

If moving the file succeed, the save in database should succeed too. If the save in database doesn't succeed, then i should revert back to temp directory or delete the file from the destination folder to be in adequacy with database. In other words, if the second action fail, the first one should fail two.

What is a good way to achieve that ?

EDIT : One solution i can see would be to check every X period of time if each file in the final destination folder has an entry in db and if it doesn't, to delete it.

Comment: I think you're approach is already ok. If the reverting of the first action fails, you can add another layer of "security" with some alerting system as slack/email message.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use promises to implement such kind of thing, For example, you need to create a user and then send a notification. So both actions are async and need to be done one after one.

```
const user = {};

// This function create user and send back a id
user.createUser = (data) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // ...you callbacks
    if (some conditions are true) {
    return resolve(id);
  } else {
    return reject();
  }
});
};

// This function finds user detail by id and send notifiaction
user.sendNotification = (id) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // ...you callbacks
    return resolve();
  });
};

user.action = async () => {
  try {
    const userId = await user.createUser(); // Wait for promise to resolve
    await user.sendNotification(userId);
    return true;
  } catch (err) {
    throw err;
  }
};

module.exports = user;
```

In the above code, you can see the `user.action()` function call 2 separate function one by one, `async/await` only works on promises, So we made that functions promisify and use it once using a keyword `await`. So, in short, you need to use promises to handle such kind of things.

I hope it helps. Happy Coding :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this is not answering the question (off topic). I am already using asynchronous code which works fine.  The goal here is not to make actions to be done one by one in an asynchronous way simply because it's already done ;)